# When did Valve make CS:GO freely available?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm new to CS:GO and recently downloaded it from steam and I wondered that such a pro game was made freely available (Free to play).But I didn't have any clue about when did Valve do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in December of 2018 that Valve made the game free to play.  [This article](https://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2018-12-06-counter-strike-global-offensive-goes-free-to-play) was released on December 6th 2018:

> ORIGINAL STORY 6/12/2018: Valve has announced today that its six-year-old, still-popular FPS Counter-Strike: Global Offensive has gone free-to-play.

Comment: In that link it has been said that it was because of the negative reviews about the game posted on steam.But why should this alternation in its business model suppress that rage? Thanks.

Comment: @spm Other way around.  People complained *because* it went free.  They did so because Valve was trying to position CS:GO as a competitor to Fortnite.